# Spring data exchange between components?

Tags: java, design-patterns, architecture, spring

Please advise me what pattern to use in following case:

I have a Java/Spring Boot application. There is a component with @KafkaListener method which receives Kafka Messages on CRUD of various subject notifications, grouped in a bigger logical groups/types/topics (e.g. topic "humans" notify on "students", "teachers", topic "devices" on "computers", "phones", etc - there is a `type` field in each message).

On receiving Kafka messages, I need to notify other (possible multiple) Spring @Component-s, i.e. Java classes that CRUD message was received, and they have to process it on their own business logic requirements.

As an options may be:

1. Spring ApplicationEvent sub-classes, containing all necessary data (DTO) which will be published (broadcast) and all interested components will subscribe to that events and will process messages if interested.
2. Declare special interfaces with methods like `onSomeSpecificMessage(specificMessage)` and all interested component will implement those interfaces, but publisher will inject lists of those interfaces and will notify each o them one by one (e.g. interfacesList.forEach(msg -> onMsg..(msg)) - Is it Observer pattern?
3. Your Option?

Comment: What's wrong with each solution? What did you try so far?

Comment: Both, but wanted to know which is better or more common practiced. Pros/Cons?